# Why won’t my phlox bloom anymore?

Tags: flowers, flowering

I purchased some beautiful pale blue phlox a month or so ago. Shortly after I planted them, all the blooms died. Some of the stems and leaves started to turn yellow. I cut off all the tops, and I continue to water them. They’re still very green, and new growth appears to be happening. But not so much as a single new flower has appeared.

[image]

**EDIT**: Here’s what the plant looked like once the flowers started to fade a bit.

[image]

Comment: Those leaves look a bit glossy for phlox. Do you know the cultivar name?

Comment: The leaves also appear to be too wide for phlox, especially the glossy-leaved cultivars. Very curious as to the cultivar's name. Do you have a photo of the plant in bloom?

Comment: I don't know anything else about the plant, but I added a photo of the plant when it just started to fade. The color used to be a slightly deeper blue.

Comment: I looked up some species, and Phlox divaricata looked exactly like the ones I purchased, in a very blue color.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, no species of perennial phlox reblooms (the annual *Phlox drummondii* may rebloom in the fall after blooming in late spring/early summer). *Phlox divaricata*, which is your ID for your plant, is a spring bloomer (mid-May into early June in my area) and once done blooming is done for the year.

Comment: Oh okay. So basically I need to just get rid of it since it's not going to keep blooming? Thanks for the info!

Comment: I recommend looking for an annual (marigolds, lantana, nasturtiums, etc.) to get consistent flowers throughout the growing season. If the planter is in shade, then you could also use coleus, which has leaves in many different colors.